# Bitrix call api rest java

Tags: bitrix

Everyone! Hi.

I'm newbie in using bitrix24. Now, i am developing to send data from third application to bitrix CRM by calling rest api.

So, could you help to know: Do bitrix support calling rest api by using java code? If yes, please help me with some examples.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

This example adds new custom field to company object

```
HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://xxxx.bitrix24.de/rest/1/xxxxx/crm.company.userfield.add/");

//@see bitrix documentation for more details https://training.bitrix24.com/rest_help/crm/contacts/crm_contact_userfield_add.php
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fields[FIELD_NAME": "MY_STRING" };
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fields[EDIT_FORM_LABEL": "My string" };
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fields[LIST_COLUMN_LABEL": "My string" };
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fields[USER_TYPE_ID": "string" };
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fields[XML_ID": "MY_STRING" };

httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));

//Execute and get the response.
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

if (entity != null) {
    InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
    try {
        // do something useful
    } finally {
        instream.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bitrix accepts rest request, from where you are gonna make does not matters .

They have this documentation that show all accepteds "operations" :
https://training.bitrix24.com/rest_help/index.php

And bitrix have a wehbook that you can setup easy, in this link bellow you will se how, but the exemple code is in PHP, but you can make the same type of request using java and a few libraries(java.net.HttpURLConnection or javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection for ssl):

https://www.bitrix24.com/about/blogs/updates/fast-bitrix24-integration-webhook-street-magic.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use bitrix24-java-api. Look for the latest version of this Library on github.

### Add Maven dependency

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
     <id>bitrix24-java-api-mvn-repo</id>
         <url>https://raw.github.com/JavaStream/bitrix24-java-api/mvn-repo/</url>
         <snapshots>
             <enabled>true</enabled>
             <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
         </snapshots>
   </repository>
</repositories>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.javastream</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-bitrix24-api</artifactId>
    <version>0.8-SNAPSHOT</version>
 </dependency>
```

Init Client in your project. You need insert yours Webhook Token and bitrix-account.

> Client client = new Client("token", "your-account.bitrix24.ru", rest_id);

```
For example, working with Lead entity:

    // Create and save new Lead
    Lead lead = new Lead();         
    lead.add_title("Torrentino");
    client.getLeadService().addNewLead(lead); 

   // Get lead by ID = 4 
   Lead lead = client.getLeadService().getLeadById(4);

   // Delete lead by ID = 4
   client.getLeadService().deleteLeadById(4);

   // Update Lead 
   Lead lead = client.getLeadService().getLeadById(4);

  // Set new values for Simple fields (like String) 
  lead.setNAME("Albert");
  lead.setLAST_NAME("Shtein");
  lead.setADDRESS("West Olympic Boulevard Apt. 100");
  lead.setCOMMENTS("Interested in price");
  lead.setSTATUS_ID(StatusID_type.NEW.getCode());
  lead.setCURRENCY_ID(CurrencyID_type.EUR.getCode());
  lead.setSOURCE_ID(SourceID_type.RECOMMENDATION.getCode());

  // In multiple fields containing lists, the data is entered differently (for example, Phone, Email, Website, IM). For example, I change the first website
  Website website = lead.getWEB().get(0);
  website.setVALUE("www.albert-best.org");
  website.setVALUE_TYPE(Website_type.OTHER.getCode());
  List<Website> websitList = new ArrayList<>();
  websitList.add(website);
  lead.setWEB(websitList);
  client.getLeadService().updateLead(lead);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of plain URL for bitrix24 search.
Yhis link you can generate in bitrix24, there is no need of password so be careful kkk

```
https://<YOUR_BITRIX_GENERATED_LINK>/crm.deal.list.json?select[]=UF_CRM_1664034965428&select[]=TITLE&select[]=UF_CRM_1664034987955&select[]=ASSIGNED_BY_ID&select[]=UF_CRM_1664035213903&select[]=UF_CRM_1664035290193&filter[CATEGORY_ID]=0&filter[%3E%3DUF_CRM_1664034965428]=2023-03-14&filter[%3C%3DUF_CRM_1664034965428]=2023-03-14&order[UF_CRM_1664034965428]=ASC&start=50
```

select is the fields you want, like SELECT clause for BDs

filter is the filter rsrsr, like WHERE CLAUSE for BDs

order is de ordenation, like ORDER BY for BDs

start is the pagination, always 50 by 50. In this example I am on page 2.

%3E%3D is URL encoded for >=

%3C%3D is URL encoded for <=